# Stretch a Tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this beautiful tree, but I have not been able to stretch it. Specifically I want to increase the distance between the first and second children and their grandchildren. Any suggestions?

```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            thick,
            l sep=0.55cm,
            s sep=0.55cm,
            child anchor=west,
            parent anchor=east,
            grow'=east,
            draw,
            anchor=west,
            node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
            edge={semithick},
            align=center,
            node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
            edge={semithick},
            forked edges,
            where n children={11}{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=2{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=6{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=8{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
        },
        %           edge path={
        %               \noexpand \path[\forestoption{edge}]
        %               (.child anchor) 
        %               -- +(-10pt,0) 
        %               |- (!u.parent anchor)
        %               \forestoption{edge label};
        %           },
        %           ver/.style={rotate=90, child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center},
        %   }
        [Mother branch, 
        [First Child
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child    []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        [Second Child
        [Grand child [ ]]
        [Grand child [] ]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This distance is to a large extent controlled by `l sep`. If you increase it to, say `l sep=1.55cm,` the distance will become larger. What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks marmot, I will like to strech the distance between the first/second child and grand child. Changing to 1.55cm only increases the distance of the grandchild not the connecting line between the first/second child and the grandchild

Comment: I added something where you can selectively increase (or decrease) these distances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can selectively increase the level distance by saying e.g.

```
where level=2{l+=0.5cm,fork sep=8mm}{},
```

where I also adjusted the `fork sep` for the optics. MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            thick,
            l sep=0.55cm,
            where level=2{l+=0.5cm,fork sep=8mm}{},         
            s sep=0.55cm,
            child anchor=west,
            parent anchor=east,
            grow'=east,
            draw,
            anchor=west,
            node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
            edge={semithick},
            align=center,
            node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
            edge={semithick},
            forked edges,
            where n children={11}{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=2{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=6{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
            where n children=8{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
        },
        [Mother branch, 
        [First Child
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child    []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        [Second Child
        [Grand child [ ]]
        [Grand child [] ]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

i'm guessing, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

which is obtained with the following *mwe*:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            grow'=east,
            anchor=west,
            node options={draw, thick, font=\sffamily},
            edge={semithick},
            forked edges,
            l sep=6mm,
            s sep=4mm,
            fork sep = 2.5mm,           % new, distance from parent to branching point
            where level=1{s sep=1mm}{}, % new
            where level=2{}{rotate=90, anchor=center} % new
        },
        [Mother branch,
        [First Child
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child    []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        [Second Child
        [Grand child [ ]]
        [Grand child [] ]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        [Grand child []]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

changes in comparison to your *mwe* are indicated with `% new`. i also remove all doubled code lines in your mwe.